# jQuery does not work properly in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Basically, I need my posts to animate when the user is hovering over them. [Here is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/hd90gtrn/1/)

It works here, but does not work on my Wordpress page. I included it using

`<script type="javascript"><?php include('js/ertikis.js');?></script>`

I tried including this in the footer file and in the index file, neither works. The script shows up on the page when inspecting it, but doesn't work.

Comment: a) I'd do that just using CSS. b) Any errors on the console?

Comment: Given the title of this question, I think that we should all stop using wordpress immediately. Apparently, jquery breaks it. That, or the way you are adding the jquery script into your page incorrectly. Does the console throw any errors? Have you got a link we could see?

Comment: I might just use CSS now.. No errors on the console. Still running the page locally so no link. The script appears correctly when inspecting the page,so I think I added it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `type` of `javascript` is not valid on `<script>`.

Can you try:
`<script type="text/javascript"><?php include('js/ertikis.js');?></script>`

or if HTML5 you can drop `type` altogether

`<script><?php include('js/ertikis.js');?></script>`

Comment: Still does not work..  I get this error in the console now : **Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):64**

line 64 : `<script type="text/javascript">var j = jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: Managed to fix it after fiddling with my index.php. However,only this method seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The standard convention for including scripts in Wordpress is to use `wp_enqueue_script()`, flagging jQuery as a dependency.

Typically this involves including your plugin and other javascript in your Wordpress theme directory, and referencing it as such:

```
<?php

// functions.php, in your theme directory

function my_assets() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'ertikis', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/ertikis.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'application', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/application.js', array( 'ertikis', 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_assets' );
```

Comment: Nope.. Is there a way to check if the functions.php file added the script correctly?